# How to run angularjs documentation locally

Tags: angularjs

I have compiled the newest angular.js and find out that links in the doc all point to absolute  URL angularjs.org/.... I want to be able to read the doc locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Local AngularJS API Docs

Here's how I hosted the **Angular.JS** documentation locally, on my **Mac**:

1. Download the zipped version of the [Angular.JS](https://angularjs.org) Build, which contains both the builds of AngularJS, as well as documentation and other extras.
2. Unzip the Angular.JS docs folder.
3. Download and install [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org).
4. Using Mac Terminal, install the npm package [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) globally so that it can be run from the command line.

`$ sudo npm install -g http-server`

5. cd to the Angular.JS docs folder and start-up `http-server`.

`$ http-server -a 127.0.0.1
Starting up http-server, serving ./ on: http://127.0.0.1:8080`

6. Use your browser to view the docs @ http://127.0.0.1:8080/index-production.html

**Note:**
Using the default served by `http-server` (http://0.0.0.0:8080) and http://0.0.0.0:8080/index-production.html in Chrome will end up in a google search. Alternatively you can create a bookmark and Chrome will stop searching for it.

Comment: It's not like it doesn't like it, but 0.0.0.0 has a special meaning in networking. It basically means that `http-server` serves the content in `:8080` in all your computer's interfaces. If you have 5 interfaces, with 5 different IP addresses. Listening on `0.0.0.0:8080` means that you can get the content from any of those 5 addresses.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the info! http://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/ | http://serverfault.com/a/300410

Comment: thanks, but this is just overkill.. why not just to have some archive with html files =/

Comment: @holms see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408510/chrome-cant-load-web-worker

Answer (score 15):

You have to run a webserver (`"python -m SimpleHTTPServer`) to properly browse the docs.

As an alternative, you might want to try `Dash` for offline documentation for many APIs - http://kapeli.com/dash

Comment: I didn't know that python supports .htaccess file. I realized that I have already installed node.js - is there any suitable alternative to python?

Comment: Warning : in order to do that 1) you have to copy angular*.js files under 'docs/' 2) doc files uses semicolons (:) in their names which is not handled in windows -> you have to use an unix. With that, offline doc works with the python server given in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

"Dash" which is mentioned in another answer costs around $20.

For a free solution, check out http://devdocs.io/

Clone the angular source code in order to have access to the docs directory of all released (and yet unreleased) versions locally.

Answer (score 4):

download the lastest version of the doc, then run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, in your browser enter the following url:  localhost:8000/index-production.html , it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a complete local AngularJS documentation, you can clone the [angular/angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) repository on Github. The nodejs webserver is already included.

You just need to install nodejs dependencies (`npm install`) and build (`grunt package`), and you can run the local webserver with `grunt webserver`.

All the documentation (API, tutorials, etc ...) will be available on your computer at http://localhost:8000/build/docs

Answer (score 3):

For a free and open source version of Dash, use [Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/) to provide offline documentation. It's also very nice when integrated with your editor (Submlime in my case).

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing a site using "localhost/your-project"
and refer the angular.js file as:
"localhost/your-project/js/angular.js"
then, you can access the docs by:
"localhost/your-project/js/docs/index.html"

Answer (score 0):

For those with **WampServer** (or anyother *AMP application ), 
Simply point your **Web Browser** to your offline docs ,

```
http://localhost/angularjs/1.5.3/docs/
```

it works like charm.