# Cross Domain Web Workers

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-domain, web-worker, xdomainrequest

I am aware that this question might be considered duplicate, but it is a new technology and I can not find a recent confirmation of my findings. I also think it potentially useful to have all the error messages in one place (feel free to add any other browsers).

trying to loads a worker script from another domain:

`new Worker('http://otherdomain.co/worker.js');`

I have set headers (using [ModHeader Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj)) to:

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

But in Chrome I get:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'http:otherdomain.co/worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin`

Safari give me:

`[Error] SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent`

Firefox gives me:

`SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

Is it still that this is not something we can do? If so, what is considered the best practise work around?

Comment: just stumbled across this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21771754/1667461

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a little late now, but [is this what you're looking for?](https://www.javascripture.com/URL#createObjectURL)

> *"Creates a url for the specified blob that can be passed to methods that expect a url. When done with the returned url, call
>   revokeObjectURL() to free the resources associated with the created
>   url."*

This method easily allows you to create a Worker using a local script instead of a remote url.

Comment: Oh, I love this one!

Answer (score 4):

You are not allowed to create cross-domain web workers.

> Note : The URI passed as parameter of the Worker constructor must obey
>   the same-origin policy . There is currently disagreement among
>   browsers vendors on what URIs are of the same-origin; Gecko 10.0
>   (Firefox 10.0 / Thunderbird 10.0 / SeaMonkey 2.7) and later do allow
>   data URIs and Internet Explorer 10 does not allow Blob URIs as a valid
>   script for workers.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

One workaround that I can think of is to create a server-side script to load the required remote JS file, and supply it to the browser from your domain.

Eg: You supply url to :

```
http://YOUR_DOMAIN/getRemoteJS.php
```

This PHP file will request the remote file on the server side, and echo it as the response, and set mime-type to application/javascript.

I have not personally tried this workaround, but you can perhaps look into it.

Good Luck!

Comment: Nice idea, mega hacky though!

Comment: Glad you like it, and I agree, its kinda hacky. Please mark it as the correct answer if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: I am holding out for a better one!

Comment: You could probably also work around this with an `<iframe>` and `postMessage`? I wouldn't go there though - it's going to be fragile and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to run cross-origin workers with:

- fetching JS code of the worker
- run worker from `data:` string or `blob:`

Working solution: https://github.com/CezaryDanielNowak/CrossOriginWorker