# How to resolve security error when working with html5 web worker?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-worker

I'm learning about web workers from this [site](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=x3SFEKTHrLf) and following the example, but I keep getting this error. What does this mean? Both my index.html and pi.js files are saved on my desktop.

> index.html:9 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker':
>   Script at 'file:///Users/jlei/Desktop/pi.js' cannot be accessed from
>   origin 'null'.

Comment: This was asked before several times. [Please use Google](https://www.google.cz/search?q=Script+at++cannot+be+accessed+from+origin+'null'). Particularly I recommend my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33432215/607407

Answer (score 1):

If your project has a tsconfig, you probably need another tsconfig for the worker thread.  Here is an example for Agular.  it is Angular 8, but I tried it in Agular 14 and it still works

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular8/angular8_web_workers.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would bet you can't do that just locally. Though I'm not all sure..
Have you tried in LAMP or similar or even on actual webspace?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

Comment: i found that it just doesn't work in chrome for locally unless you change the settings. or you can just use safari or firefox

Comment: You should be able to do that locally provided you use relative paths. The only exception is google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using Angular and you landed on this question**:
I also had this issue. I had a `tsconfig.worker.json` setup and it was linked correctly in `angular.json` and I followed the [Angular Web Worker Documention](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker) to initialize the Worker,
i.e. 
`new Worker(new URL('./app.worker', import.meta.url))` 
The only problem was that Webpack or TSC (not sure which one) didn't resolve the relative names correctly because the `baseUrl` in my `tsconfig.app.json` was set to `"baseUrl": ""` so I changed it `"baseUrl": "./"` and now it works as it should both in chrome and FF.

Comment: OP here was clearly not facing an Angular issue (The first Angular version was released a few months after this question was asked). You may consider searching for an existing question facing specifically that issue. If you don't find one, you may even consider asking a new question and self-answer it.

Comment: This was the first result I found when I searched on google for angular webworker and this issue, which means others may land on this exact same post. That's why I posted it here.
I editied it, to reflect the fact that's more for those who stumbled on this question.