# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at papaparse.mi.js

Tags: javascript, file, csv, xapi

I tried to play with importing CSV data as xAPI Statement in LRS. I tired to followed the step stated. But i cannot fletch the data. It throws a error." Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script atUncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at papaparse.min.js

Here is the github link for it which i tried. https://github.com/mariocoski/csv-to-xapi

This is the error that i am getting 
papaparse.min.js:6 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///Users/dassintern/Documents/ayash/csv-to-xapi-master/js/lib/papaparse.min.js?papaworker' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.
    at f (file:///Users/dassintern/Documents/ayash/csv-to-xapi-master/js/lib/papaparse.min.js:6:11265)
    at Object.t [as parse] (file:///Users/dassintern/Documents/ayash/csv-to-xapi-master/js/lib/papaparse.min.js:6:91)
    at HTMLInputElement. (file:///Users/dassintern/Documents/ayash/csv-to-xapi-master/js/csv-parser-extension.js:60:8)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:3:8549)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:3:5252)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are seeing this in Chrome then the answer probably has to do with loading from a local filesystem rather than over HTTP. The key is the message "cannot be accessed from origin 'null'" where a local `file://` load will have a `null` origin. See [Chrome can't load web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408510/chrome-cant-load-web-worker).

Comment: Thank you, its because Chrome doesn't let you load web workers when running scripts from a local file. Used XAMP but its does work  in firefox as well. Thank you again mate!!

Comment: @Brian In my case, I am trying to implement the dos program using js-dos, But I am stuck over this construct worker issue, it's neither working from localhost, UAT, nor live server.

Comment: Try modifying your local browser option, for instance in firefox changing the security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy remove this problem.